# Displaying SSIS variabe values in Integration Services Dashboard

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis, ssis-2012

I have an SSIS package that executes stored procedures which return output parameters into ssis variables. How can I easily display these variables content in the Integration Services Dashboard ? 
Basically after a SSIS Package is run I would like to know if the return code of the SPs and some performance counters (records transferred, etc.)